# How do I get <partial> tag helper to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to this and I am struggling with using partial name. I have a partial view that simply shows a Create button. The partial view is in the `Views/Shared`. I have tried `<partial name="_CreateButtonPartial" />`, but it does not show the button. However `@Html.Partial("_CreateButtonPartial")` does show it. When I use the latter I get a warning that says ***"Consider using  Tag Helper"***. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use the @Html.Partial("_CreateButtonPartial") html helper? Is there a reason you want to avoid it? Are you using asp.net core?

Comment: I am use asp.net core and wanted to use <partial> because I was trying to replicate a tutorial. As I said above using the other method gives a warning suggesting I should use <partial>

Comment: ΟK! You've tagged your question as an asp.net MVC 5 question and I got confused. I will look into it by using asp net core if you haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Have you tried <partial name="_CreateButtonPartial" /> and it doesn't display anything? It doesn't show the button or anything at all? If you add the following div in your partial it is not diplayed?  <div>This is a partial page</div>?

Comment: I have managed to replicate the whole project from the start and now can get <partial> working. Don't know what was wrong orginally. Sometimes it is better to start all over again.